# nslookup on ubuntu

Tags: apt, aptitude

I am using a Debian-based Docker image. In the image, I need `nslookup` but I could not find how to install that.

Which apt package contains `nslookup`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*nslookup* is contained within the *dnsutils* package.

You can install it using *apt*:

```
sudo apt install dnsutils
```